# How can I increase the time a user stays logged in after inactivity in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I'm using Keycloak. The problem is that it's idle time is extremely low and it has a very bad UX out of the box. I need to log in like 50 times per day. Each 5 minutes I don't work with it, it logs out.

I went into `Realm Settings` => `Tokens` and changed the `Access Token Lifespan For Implicit Flow` to 30 days, but it had no effect.

How can I stay logged-in longer in Keycloak? How can I increase the idle time?

Comment: Sorry, I did not test for this answer. I will re-open after testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are in `Implicit Flow` ?
If you really are, do you have SSO ?
If it is, you should check `SSO Session Max`.

If not, you might want to try this also : `Access Token Lifespan`

++

Comment: It seemed to work. However, I actually increased so many values that I'm not sure if this was the cause. I need to test more.

Comment: Any update here ?

Comment: yes it worked. Thank you so much. I changed two values related to SSO and it worked.